# Let $f : R_+ \to R $ be a function that satisfies for all $x > 0, f(x) \geq 0$ and $f$ is stricly concave, show that $f$ is mon. increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (differentiable) function that satisfies the following
>
> - $f(x) = 0\iff x =0$
> - $\forall x > 0, f(x) \geq 0$
> - $f$ is stricly concave
>
> Show that $f$ is monotonically increasing

My lecturer did the following in proof class

*Lecturer's Proof:* By concavity of $f$ we have $f(x) < f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f'(x_0)$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. Suppose $f$ was not monotonically increasing, then there exists an $x_0 \in [0, \infty)$ for which $f'(x_0) < 0$, hence there exists an  $x \in \mathbb{R_+}$ such that $f(x) < 0$ (using concavity of $f$) contradicting positivity of $f$.

---

But I am having trouble understanding one part of the proof. How does once conclude by concavity of $f$ we have $f(x) < f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + f'(x_0)$ for all $x \in [0, \infty) = \mathbb{R_+}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for a concave function the tangent line at any point on the graph of the function doesn't lie below the graph. But the equation of a tangent line at any point $x_0\in\text{dom} f$ (domain of $f$) is given by 
$$f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$
i.e. the first order Taylor approximation of $f$ at $x=x_0$. Since function is concave by the above geometric property of its tangent lines it must be the case that for any $x\in\text{dom}f$ we must have
$$f(x)\leqslant f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$